# Repeat each row n times in a matrix and add a column of 1*n next to each part

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to repeat each row of my matrix and add another column next to it.

Imagine here is my matrix

```
A = [[11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16], [17, 18]]
```

and I want repetition of 2 times for each row, then the result will be

```
B = [[1, 11, 12], [2, 11, 12], [1, 13, 14], [2, 13, 14], [1, 15, 16], [2, 15, 16], [1, 17, 18], [2, 17, 18]]
```

I already tried below code

```py
k = 2
B = [A] * k
```

which gives me error of memory in my full code

I do not know how to use panda and I am using numpy.
Is there any way to use numpy in efficient way without facing memory error, in my case,

And get the correct reply?

P.S.: I didn't add my code as I am working with huge dataset plus it is just one little little piece of whole code!

Comment: The code you provided does not cause an _"error of memory"_ or any other kind of error. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `[A]*k` creates an array of length `k` with each field set to `A`. If you change `A`, all elements of the array of arrays will change as well (because they share the same reference). If you use `A*k` you'll get a new array that doesn't share any memory with `A` and thus can be safely manipulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
k = 2
B = A * k
```

instead of

```
k = 2
B = [A] * k
```

To add the new index column, you could do this

```
for i, sub_list in B:
    sub_list.insert(i, i+1) # starting from index 1 instead of 0
```

Since lists are mutable, there is no need to reassign B.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Here is my reply which solved memory problem too.
#I guess memory problem was due to exceeding array limit!!!
#I do not know HOW but below code was practically correct. 
A = np.repeat(A, k, axis=0)
AB = [[1], [2]]
AB = np.reshape(AB, (-1,1))
AB = np.tile(AB,((len(A)//k),1))
B = np.hstack((AB, A))
```